# Solr Queries With Dashes

Tags: solr, solrnet

I am currently using solr edismax to do searches on our website. What I'm looking to do, is essentially have dashes get ignored.

So if I search the words, `"wi-fi adapter"`. And I have a document, with a title, "wifi adapter". I'll get no results.

I am currently using `solr.MappingCharFilterFactory` to map dashes to spaces. This is what my `text_general` fieldtype looks like in my schema.

```
  <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

My mapping.txt contains the line..

```
"-" => " "
```

So what this rule does, is it converts the dashes to a space.

So if I search "wi fi adapter", it will always show the same results as `"wi fi adapter"`, but won't show results for `"wifi adapter"`.

Is there any way to treat dashes like this? Essentially I'd want to treat `"wifi adapter", "wi-fi adapter", and "wi fi adapter"` the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory` for your analyzer. It has lot many attributes that could be used. I have listed few.

The `WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory` has many attributes.

`generateWordParts` : (integer, default 1) If non-zero, splits words at delimiters. For example: `"CamelCase", "hot-spot" → "Camel", "Case", "hot", "spot"`

`preserveOriginal` : (integer, default 0) If non-zero, the original token is preserved: `"Zap-Master-9000" → "Zap-Master-9000", "Zap", "Master", "9000"`

`catenateWords` : (integer, default 0) If non-zero, maximal runs of word parts will be joined: `"hot-spot-sensor’s" → "hotspotsensor"`

So in your case it would be like

```
<fieldType name="text_wd" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
          <!-- Splits words based on whitespace characters --> 
          <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
          <!-- splits words at delimiters based on different arguments --> 
          <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="1" catenateWords="1"/>
          <!-- Transforms text to lower case -->   
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>

        <analyzer type="query">
          <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

The more information on it would be found at [Fiters available in solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html)

Comment: This is a correct answer, of course, and this is a preferred way to do it. But, original question might be related to phrase queries that can be converted to span queries for some complex cases, so be aware of https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/LUCENE/issues/LUCENE-7398 .

Comment: @Nikolay : I will check again from my side if anything can be done...waiting for the   Paul for his feedback...

Comment: Your answer is perfect, I just added minor warning for Paul on Lucene bug that break this in some rare cases.